# Pagination problem on the homepage in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am using the following code for the homepage pagination. The problem is that the posts are not changing whenever I try to switch between the pages but I could see the pagination changes in the permalink. Can someone please help me to solve this issue?

```
<?php
    $ourCurrentPage = get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
        $args = array(
          'post_type'=> 'post',
          'order'    => 'DESC',
          'posts_per_page' => 4,
          'page' => $ourCurrentPage,

        );              
        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        
                    <div class="post-content" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="200">
                       -------------
                       -------------
                </div>
           
        
</article><!-- #post-## -->
        <?php endwhile; 
echo paginate_links(array(
'total' => $my_query->max_num_pages
));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is 'paged' not 'page'

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'post',
        'order'    => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'paged' => $ourCurrentPage,
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Now the posts are changing dynamically whenever I click the page button but there is no activity in the button because the active link always pointing to page 1 even when I switch to pages 2, 3, and so on.